# Google Sheets - Multiple outcomes using If And statements?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm working on categorizing tires and rims that I own. I want the sheet to look into the "Width", "Ratio" and "Rim Size" columns to provide me with data to determine which car it would fit on.

For example: D2=215, E2=55, F2=16
This would be a tire of 215/55/R16.

So in pseudocode:

```
if D2=215 && E2=55 && F2=16
then C2="Fits Ford Crown Vic/Taurus"
```

And to expand, I would hope it could be easier with a switch statement so that I could make it more complicated.

```
if D2=(between 215 and 235) && E2=(between 55 and 65) && F2=(between 16 and 18)
then C2="Fits Ford Crown Vic/Taurus/Charger"
```

Would it be easier to write a script to go with it instead?

Comment: Welcome. Let's back up a step. You've got three attributes of tire/rim information. Those attributes are valid for certain vehicles. Do you have a list of vehicles with relevant tyre/rim data that you can cross-match to your tyre/rim data? That list needs to in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks and no, I have them in my head so I guess if I laid them out in a 2nd page, it would work better? Ive never worked with grabbing data from another sheet

Comment: Yes, put the tire attributes on a second page; there are many options for accessing the data from another page. Just for the moment though, is it possible that multiple cars might have the same tire width/ratio/rim-size?